# Vue v-show update after changing data with method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm iterating over this array of object's and in each object there's a property - `keyword.edited` which iniitalized with the value - `false`
the all loop looks like this:

```
<tr v-for="(keyword, index) in keywords">
    <td>{{keyword.tag_name}}</td>
    <td @click="edit_keyword(index)">
        <el-input-number v-show="keyword.edited" :step="step" size="small" v-model="keyword.max_bid"></el-input-number>
    </td>
</tr>
```

now since initalized with `false` none of the keywords will show.
problem is when i click `edit_keyword(index)` the value of the relevant keyword changes to true:

```
edit_keyword(index){
    this.keywords[index].edited = !this.keywords[index].edited
    return  this.keywords[index].edited
}
```

but the DOM won't update, or in other words the relevant keyword won't show as i expected.
any idea how can i achive this one? tried to implement same idea with computed property as well and still didn't work...

Comment: I cannot get your idea very well. DOM should be updated automatically. Would you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: try to log your index, and do some error control maybe the issue is there

Comment: so basically `<td @click="keyword.edited = !keyword.edited">` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property you are changing is not reactive, so vue is not [watching](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) it changes. If you update property of the object you need to tell Vue with $set method:

```javascript
edit_keyword(index) {
    this.$set(this.keyswords[index], 'edited', !this.keywords[index].edited)
}
```

Comment: The updated syntax is this.$set(propName, index, newValue); so for example this.$set(this.show, index, !this.show[index]);